# SSIS 2008 - Float value exported to exponential value in Flat file destination

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to export the table to flat file destination. Float column value (0.0911780821917808) is exported into 9.1178082191780821E-2 in flat file.

**Table**
create table Test
(
col1 float
)

**Col1**
0.0911780821917808

Exporting this table to flat file destination. However exported to value "9.1178082191780821E-2" in .txt file. However correct value is coming in the DataViewer after OLE DB Source.

Please guide to export the value as it is to flat file.

Advance thanks for all your time

Regards,

Stalin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues before and what proved to be the safest way is by converting to string at source via STR function. For example you can read your table in the OLEDB Source with a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(col1,25,18) ) Col1casted
FROM
TEST
```

Then you may need to recreate the flat file destination (or change the data types)

In this example I'm setting the converted value to a 25 long of which 18 are decimals but you can adjusted to make sure it covers the range of values in your table.

For Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.0911780821917808267712341,'9D9999999999999999') FROM DUAL;
```

above the format is set to 16 decimals, example in sql fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=487fe7bf6cf3a2264f988523e5ac7a3d

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using Oracle database. Could you let me know what is the equivalent function in Oracle.

Comment: I tried by querying that field by TO_CHAR(field). It is coming as ".091178082191780821917808219178082191781"

Comment: underlying table field is Number field without precision and scale. So i need to export the value as it is to flat file.

Comment: Yes, TO_CHAR should work, you can set the format as well. That long number probably the actual internally stored in Oracle, you can leave it like that or set the number of decimals according to the business needs. I've updated the answer with an example.